# How to limit users to N cores?

Tags: ssh, users, multi-core

I have an SSH server where users login to do various tasks. The problem is I have 4 cores, and one user is running tasks on 4. How can I limit the number of cores any given user can use?

This is not a virtual machine.

UPDATE:
I was reading  /etc/security/limits.conf 
and saw

```
#*               soft    core            0
#root            hard    core            100000
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
```

I tried setting this up so that a user is limited to 3 processes.
but the user gets

```
 -bash: fork: retry: No child processes
```

in their terminal.

I have started looking into ulimit, and quota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**taskset(1)** may help you. It can set the core number for one process. 
You can use **ps(1)** to get all the process of target user. For example,

```
housezet@arch: ~
$ ps aux | awk '/^housezet/{print $2}' | xargs -l taskset -p 0x00000001
```

This wil limit housezet's current process only use one core.
And if limiting cpu usage is also acceptable, you can also consider using **cpulimit(1)**.

Comment: I am going back and forth with this solution. How would I set this to run when the user logs in?

Comment: @j0h For systemwide, create a service under **/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/** or startup script under **/etc/init.d/** with something like **watch(1)** to repeat this command. Putting script under **/etc/profile.d/** will make it works when user logs in. You can look at [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting) for more about autostarting.

Comment: If a have 8 cores and do this for 2 users limiting to 4 cores each. would it mean that when they run the desktop (mate ) and chrome in mate, that chrome could use between 1 and 4 cores per user? That's what I want to do. They would log in via vnc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any existing tool that would handle what you're after, as it's not a particularly easy thing to do.  Handling of which process goes where isn't done in userspace.

The only way I can think of to kind of do what you're after is to use `ulimit` to set the maximum amount of CPU time, which would prevent a user from hogging everything too much.  You can also change a user's `nice` level, so if a particular user is slamming the CPU you can lower their prority.