# System slowing Doooowwwwn - swap file? (18.4.2)

Tags: swap

I have an Fujitsu LIFEBOOK A series i3 Quad Core 6Gb RAM Laptop
I do have many things running at once like Chrome Web browser with 10 tabs-(ish) open (Youtube vids(1 or 2)  and general browsing),
 Cura and/or Slicer PE and
File system - system monitor and other general stuff running,
and a second monitor.
500Gb H-drive-70% Free
On average  60% of RAM used.
BUT 
The O.S seems to have slowed down over the last 6 months.... since loading and setting it up.
What swap file size or other system settings could possibly optimize things or would re-installing the O.S or another O.S.... 
I was running 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish up to 6 months ago but it became unstable as well, I didn't realise till then that it wasn't official,now it is, would that be better?

I'm new to Linux just over a year but prefer it 110% over Windows, which was ~~~~~Sh!t when I first used it (Win 3.0) to Win 7 (my last version -  i couldn't bare it further) - (my opinion)

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Consider using cgroups to limit process resources so that they don't consume too much memory and/or cpu. https://askubuntu.com/a/1108307/295286 While the post is specific to CPU configuration, there's a few other links there which talk about limiting memory usage as well

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting your `swappiness` to 10 or less. This will reduce how often your system uses the swap. I've found that this significantly increases performance. (Not sure why it's not the default.)

First check the current value on your system:

`$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

It's most likely set to something like 60. Assuming it is, test it temporarily with:

`sysctl vm.swappiness=10`

Assuming that did something for you, set it permanently by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and set the property `vm.swappiness` to 10.

Comment: Thank you, think I've got some studying to do!